# Multiple regression for pricing an airplane ticket

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis

I am trying to find the relationship between price of an airplane ticket and multiple variables like (how early you can book the ticket, the season of flying, the day of week of flying, minimum stay, one-way or return).  The Goal is to have an total average ticket price and the price effect of the variables. I have the data available and I am looking for a suitable approach to solve this problem.

Can you give any suggestions for regression approach?

Comment: What about starting with a multiple linear regression (`lm` function in R), perhaps with ARIMA errors (exchange `lm` for `arima` with exogenous regressors)?

Answer (score 1):

The most basic way to get started with the problem you describe is a multiple linear regression.

To get started you may try predict the price with all your indeendent variable. In all (or maybe most) programs you get an estimation of significant of each predictor that gives you a feeling which predictors are relevant for the price and which aren't.

Depending on your data you might find a multilevel regression approach for suitable. E.G. a random intercept model with airline as grouping predictor.

For more detailed suggestions, you might want to describe your data in more detail.